# Interviewing for positions without a formal degree

Tags: interviewing

I started a Software Engineering degree in 2012 but after 1 and a half years I couldn't continue.

I had an internship as a Programmer and after that I didn't have time for university anymore, only for working. After that more than 3 years in experience in multi-national companies working as a Programmer.

But, in my country they have [titulitis](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/spanish-english/titulitis).
Now I can't find a job because for each interview, the interviewer agrees that I am experienced in the technology they use and quizzes prove it. But at the end, even after 2+ interview sessions, they say: "sorry, you dont have the title, we won't hire you".

I'm kind of furious because:
 1- They knew it from the beginning (it's stated clearly in my CV), but they made me waste time and gave me hope.
 2- Having a title doesnt give you all the knowledge needed for a job.

**How can I make them ignore the fact I don't have the title and stand out as the experienced programmer I am?**

Note: experienced but obviously with so much to learn.

Answer (score 3):

Well, If you can't find a job because you miss the title I know there are ways to have some kind of programming certifications without having to go back to university.

I don't know if it is global but in my country they have [Open Classroom](https://openclassrooms.com/) where some people get some certifications. Those classes are called MOOC (Massive Open Online Courses) and I'm sure you can find one in Spanish. Of course it is not the same as following a complete university degree but it is worth the trial. It will show your interviewer that you do have some skills and you can use your unusual path to show that you were able to learn on your own most of the things you know and that you are eager to learn more in your professional carreer.

Comment: Im always learning something new until I have the possibility to continue my university studies. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Some of those path reward a degree delivered by the Minister of Education. https://openclassrooms.com/paths/. _Certains parcours amènent même jusqu’à l’obtention d’un titre de niveau reconnu par l’État, comme dans une école ou une université traditionnelle !_ **Some path gives a title known by the State as one delivered by a school or a University**.

Comment: @MickMRCX thank you for your comment. You have quizzes and other kind of exercices that you have to submit, in addition to quality time with a teacher who can answer to your questions online just like a regular online university class would.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that you should look for a job outside of your country. You don't even need to move, there are many remote programming jobs available. I currently work in a software company with exclusively remote workers.

Frankly it seems ridiculous to me that people would care so much about a degree in an industry where most people seem to not have a relevant degree at all. According to a [survey conducted on Stack Overflow](http://qz.com/649409/two-out-of-three-developers-are-self-taught-and-other-trends-from-a-survey-of-56033-developers/): 69% of programmers are at least partly self-taught, and fewer than 35% have a Computer Science or related degree. I thought this was the norm globally, but I guess not. Which is even weirder considering how much companies rely on skill tests. They'll give you [online coding tests](https://www.testdome.com/), whiteboard coding tests, technical questions, trial projects, and whatever else they come up with, which is not a bad thing if it's done properly, but it just seems like skill would carry far more weight than a degree would in that case.

Comment: Very well explained answer! I understand lawyers and doctors to have the title but software? In the degree you study 2-3 languages and the rest is self-taught and practice and practice. Friends of mine that finished the degree dont even feel like they can work at a company with their current knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Hey You went far ahead in an informal career and now expecting a formal future. Off course this is going to be a problem. But wait it can become your strength! Have you tried freelancing? Try out some contacts and get some reasonable work. And how about doing an external course for the title (Only if you want a 'formal' job). And hey, You can start your own firm!

Comment: What do you mean by informal? Hahah freelancing at my age and with no title won't be nothing but laughs. About the own firm... Not even a remote possibility. Thanks for replying

Comment: Bro I'm doing Freelancing since I was 16 and know a guy who's doing that since he was 13! People don't look at degree if they really need good work that's the way freelancing goes up.

Comment: Wow, thats awesome. you freelance for india companies or other countries also? here in Spain I dont think this would work

Comment: @lois6b Your English is pretty solid, you're not limited to Spanish companies. London companies are always hiring freelancers, often working remotely.